# How to secure a portable USB thumb drive?

Tags: windows, encryption, usb-flash-drive, bitlocker

I need to encrypt data on a USB thumb drive that will be used on many different versions of Windows, including:  Windows 7 variants, Windows 8 and 8.1, and Windows 10 Pro and Home versions.

I know I can use `bitlocker to go` on my Windows 10 Pro PC, but I think the thumb drive can only be unlocked on other Windows 10 Pro computers, and not Home versions etc. that don't support bitlocker.

Is my understanding correct, and if so, what is the best way to encrypt thumb drives that need to be truly portable on all common Windows variants?

Comment: You might be able to _decrypt_ the bitlocker-to-go encrypted USB drive on Windows 10 home. It is worth trying on another USB device to see if it works before trying with the USB you need to use (or you could back-up data from the USB and test on it first). Remember that if encryption fails somehow and you are locked out, you can still completely erase it and start again; make sure your backups are intact before doing this if the data is important.

Comment: You will need to use 3rd party encryption software to do what you want>>>>>>https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Portable%20Mode.html

Comment: @Moab, a friend of mine just made the same suggestion. I've been reading that exact page and it looks useful.  Thanks for the confirmation!